# Cannot display image in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've tried displaying an image with laravel using a Query-- The images are stored in the storage directory and a symlink with "public" has already been established.

I have tried using:
`src="{{storage_path('app/public/'.$post->post_image)}}"`

`src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->post_image) }}"`

`src="{{$post->post_image}}"`

Testing, I discovered I could use a static path in order to succesfully display the imaage like so:

`src="{{ asset('storage/images/image_name.jpeg')}}"`

However, this is not what I'm looking for.

The query `{{$post->post_image}}` returns the following:

127.0.0.1:8000/images/image_name.jpeg

EDIT: If I go edit the database and add "storage/" before the url of the image, then I can use `src="{{asset($post->post_image)}}"` to display it.

As mentioned before, I already tried `src="{{asset('storage/' . $post->post_image)}}` without altering the database.

Comment: You can use `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to change `127.0.0.1:8000` into `storage`.

Comment: This didnt work, after doing this nothing happened.

Comment: What does the `post_image` look like in the database?

Comment: images/file_name.jpg

Comment: @RRios That's weird. `127.0.0.1:8000` should have access to your public folder.

Comment: The image is stored as images/file_name.jpg. When I try using `{{post->post_image}}` to write the route it comes out as `127.0.0.1:8000/images/file_name.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You must save the relative path of the image, after this, you can access as follows:

```
src="{{ asset('storage/'. $post->post_image )}}"
```

for more info: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: Tried this. Not only does it not work, but it also breaks my css.

Answer (score 0):

Only store the image name in your db.

Don't add the path.

You can have a static method in that model that return the path as a string like (return "images/app";)

You can have another method that return a image_url
Which is going to be the path + image name

Comment: The image in the database is images/file_name.jpg, I only tried to add "storage/" as a way to test if there was something wrong with the path I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Storage::url` could help here.

In your Post model, you can define a url helper like so:

```
public function url()
{
    return Storage::url($this->post_image);
}
```

Don't forget to import the Storage facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

And then retrieve image like so:

```
{{ $post->url() }}
```

Also ensure you have a symbolic link created:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

#### UPDATED

In `.env` add the below:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

It changes the default `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` to `public` in `config/filesystems.php` which means it now uses the below config in the same file

```
'public' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
     'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
     'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Then run the command `php artisan config:cache`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: Still nothing, I get this:  http://localhost/storage/http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/image_name.jpg

Comment: `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public` 

was already set in the .env file. The symlink was already stablished and nothing changed when I ran `php artisan config:cache.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contribution, here's how I fixed it using contributions from jstarnate & Abiola:

I created a url helper and properly formatted using str_replace like so:

```
    public function url()
{
    return str_replace("http://localhost/storage/http://127.0.0.1:8000/","http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/",Storage::url($this->post_image));
}
```